# Google Sheet outputs an error when combining two IFs

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, nested-if

Can't figure our why the formula is wrong, it outputs an #error

```
=IF(AND(($E6<=O$5);($F6>=O$5));"A";"")OR(IF(AND(($E6<=O$5);($h6>=O$5));"X";""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(($E6<=O$5)*($F6>=O$5); "A"; 
 IF(($E6<=O$5)*($H6>=O$5); "X"; ))
```